# pip doesn't see setuptools

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv

I am migrating from python2 to python3.

I created a virtualenv with `python3 -m venv py3` and am trying to `pip install -r requirements.txt` but it says

```
Collecting mock==1.0.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 8))
  Using cached mock-1.0.1.tar.gz
  setuptools must be installed to install from a source distribution
```

I checked my virtualenv and it does have setuptools:

```
(py3) 1111:d3 1111$ ls py3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/
__pycache__         easy_install.py         pip-6.0.8.dist-info     setuptools
_markerlib          pip             pkg_resources           setuptools-12.0.5.dist-info
```

but when I still try to reinstall setuptools it says

```
(py3) 1111:d3 1111$ pip install setuptools
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
```

So I have 2 questions:

1. why doesn't it see setuptools in virtualenv folder?
2. why does it look in Python 2 folders instead of Python 3?

Thanks!

Comment: In your `py3` virtualenv, can you verify that the correct `pip` is being used? I.e., try `which pip` and tells us the result. Also, try the same with `pip3` and see if that happens to be the `pip` you can use for your `virtualenv`.

Comment: `(py3) 1111:d3 1111$ which pip`  `/Users/1111/_realpython/d3/py3/bin/pip`. The same goes for `which pip3`: 
`/Users/1111/_realpython/d3/py3/bin/pip3`

Comment: if I do `pip3 install setuptools` it still says I already have it in my 2.7 folder.

Answer (score 9):

This is not an answer to your questions, but for me it was easier to reinstall the virtual environment than trying to solve the issue. After setting up a new virtualenv, I had no problem installing or updating packages again.

Answer (score 4):

In my case it helped to install `setuptools` under `pip` user:

`pip install -U pip setuptools`

Answer (score 3):

This one worked for me:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install setuptools
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the above recreating a virtualenv to not work. However I destroyed my virtualenv, and then upgraded pip and virtualenv and this issue resolved itself.

pip install -U virtualenv

pip install -U pip

Comment: This is the correct answer, although I believe the pip portion may be unnecessary.  What is happening is that the virtualenv is using its own version of setuptools, not the version installed with the default python install.  On a box with a very old installation of virtualenv (1.11.6), my default setuptools was 33.1.1, but the installed version within the virtualenv was 3.6. This caused a dependency in requirements.txt to attempt to upgrade setuptools which entirely broke the installation run.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do

cp /usr/bin/python2 /path/to/my-virtualenv/bin/python2
or

cp /usr/bin/python3 /path/to/my-virtualenv/bin/python3

For me, it solved a similar problem.